# openssl: how can i get public key from modulus

Tags: php, openssl, rsa, modulus

I generate a pair of keys using openssl:

```
shell> ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/mike/.ssh/id_rsa): /path/to/test_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /path/to/test_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /path/to/test_rsa.pub.
```

And then, I generate modulus from private key:

```
shell> openssl rsa -in /path/to/test_rsa -noout -modulus > /path/to/modulus.txt
```

Now, is there any way to get test_rsa.pub(public key) just from modulus?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, it must use an exponent addition. But, if I have modulus and exponent, can I get the public key?

Comment: I found a post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420259/generate-rsa-public-key-from-modulus-and-exponent-in-bytes-in-objective-c , but it used object-c, actually I want a PHP solution.

Comment: How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116907/rsa-get-exponent-and-modulus-given-a-public-key

Comment: An RSA key is a pair of integers `exponent,modulus`. So, the answer is no, you cannot create a usable key from just modulus. Though many implementations do use a fixed public key exponent such as `65537`.

Comment: @Mike.G I think you should update your question to indicate that you want the public key from the modulus and the exponent.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the public key in a more standardized format using [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$modulus = 'yEQs2LxSHBZgZCH0rRQQy9kmry8g2tNhQL1B9f5azNz9Ce9pXPgSRjVUo1B9Ggb/FK3jy41wWd2IfS6rse3vBzRsabMj29CVODM/19yZPmwEmjJHCgYd+AA2qweKZanDp4FLsSw/kyV5WoPN16GHEMLmLGkJFNIWtzzH5jV+S80=';
$exponent = 'AQAB';

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$modulus = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($modulus), 256);
$exponent = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($exponent), 256);

$rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent));
$rsa->setPublicKey();

echo $rsa->getPublicKey();
```

Comment: Is there a way we can achieve this without the phpseclib library?