# Generating public key using modulus and exponent in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have this pre-request postman script:

```js
const modulus = session.rsa.M;
const exponent = session.rsa.E;           
const rsaKey = pmlib.rs.KEYUTIL.getKey({ n: modulus, e: exponent });
const encodedPassword = pmlib.rs.KJUR.crypto.Cipher.encrypt(session.id + '**' + password, rsaKey, 'RSA');
```

And now I want to do this using PHP. First I send a request to get session that contains id, modulus and exponent, then I need to encrypt password and session to send to perform login action and get cookies. Any help for that?

EDITED:
I tried this code using node js and I get public key:

```js
const KEYUTIL = require('jsrsasign').KEYUTIL;
const KJUR = require('jsrsasign');

const modulus = session.rsa.M; // ADA6FB0A9B123950AE71EB0A4A90426156CC7545A3F5617096E7A0C095773B413FCA9DF50C231CA4804991C76BB477D721E363E0C7B61852AAC66134D43E21F3A7433C275C62B05E1CA9C5E750FB13B5DD3E6FBC2415C0EE8D23119CA375CE35307DDF828D40FC15CBA2CA545786B7D236B4A45508775250CC5AC376B29DB129
const exponent = session.rsa.E; // 010001
const rsaKey = KEYUTIL.getKey({ n: modulus, e: exponent });
const pem = KJUR.KEYUTIL.getPEM(rsaKey);
console.log(pem);
```

And when I try this code using php with exact modulus and exponent, I get a different public key:

```php
use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;
use phpseclib3\Math\BigInteger;

$modulus = $session['rsa']['M'];
$exponent = $session['rsa']['E'];

$rsa_key = PublicKeyLoader::load([
    'e' => new BigInteger(base64_decode($exponent), 256),
    'n' => new BigInteger(base64_decode($modulus), 256),
]);

echo '<pre>';
echo ($rsa_key);
echo '</pre>';

openssl_public_encrypt(data, $encoded, $rsa_key);
$encoded = bin2hex($encoded);
```

I want it to be the same because my code is doing fine in js.

Sample key by JS:

```html
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCtpvsKmxI5UK5x6wpKkEJhVsx1
RaP1YXCW56DAlXc7QT/KnfUMIxykgEmRx2u0d9ch42Pgx7YYUqrGYTTUPiHzp0M8
J1xisF4cqcXnUPsTtd0+b7wkFcDujSMRnKN1zjUwfd+CjUD8FcuiylRXhrfSNrSk
VQh3UlDMWsN2sp2xKQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Sample Key by PHP:

```html
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIHgMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4HOADCBygKBwA/RBAPQ/AfeOQOQtuQthAutwONR
QtdONd9tvBfNfeNPBOxdRRduOAdAwee9+9QOtdBNtu/dvPAfQ+txfew9xNRevfRA
de/e+A+d+d/eu+9OudRfRfAgvPOfPeOAtfQuAd+w9uhfeBNxfddQ9QdwOwOe9g+A
QNdNwudt+/dRdhNPQhNQ9BQPdAhNfQewQuwew/egNNgAg++e+NQABPee+wNRe9Ou
eguxffRfBOAweQdwhA9edfQQ+BNBetwuROghNQIFANNdNNM=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What help do you need exactly? See also [ask]

Comment: Meaning, you want your js code convert into php?

Comment: @ADyson I do not know how to convert M and E to a public key

Comment: @Keyboard Corporation Not exactly, I do not know how to convert M and E to a public key

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you need then, because at the moment it simply reads like you want someone to convert that JS code into PHP for you. (Bear in mind that this site isn't just a free write-my-code service. We expect you to make some attempt to research and solve your issue, and demonstrate that here, so that a) we don't just get freeloaders and b) we don't have to spend time on repeating things you might have already tried). That way it's actually a useful question for the community, not just a code request.

Comment: @ADyson edited my question

Comment: It's not clear from your JavaScript code if session.rsa.M and session.rsa.E are Base64 encoded or not? I would try changing the base to 16 if your inputs are hexadecimal, or remove the base parameter if they're decimal. n PHP, you can use openssl_public_encrypt for RSA encryption. Assuming $rsa_key is your public key and $data is the string you want to encrypt

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com added a sample in code, and I tried 16 and still I have the same problem

Comment: In your both modulus and exponent are in hexadecimal format. If they are in a different format (like base64), you will need to decode or convert them appropriately.

Comment: This looks similar, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58562670/4832389

Answer (score 1):

The way the modulus and exponent being used to generate the public keys are different. You're using `KEYUTIL.getKey` from the `jsrsasign`, which takes the modulus and exponent as hexadecimal strings. Then, you're using the `PublicKeyLoader::load` from the `phpseclib3` in your php, which takes the modulus and exponent as **base64-encoded** binary strings. So, to generate the same key as the js in php, you need to convert the modulus and exponent from hexadecimal to php base64.

```
use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;
use phpseclib3\Math\BigInteger;

// Get the modulus and exponent from the session
$modulus = $session['rsa']['M'];
$exponent = $session['rsa']['E'];

// Convert the modulus and exponent from hexadecimal to base64
$modulus = base64_encode(hex2bin($modulus));
$exponent = base64_encode(hex2bin($exponent));

// Generate the public key
$rsa_key = PublicKeyLoader::load([
  'e' => new BigInteger($exponent, 256),
  'n' => new BigInteger($modulus, 256),
]);

// Convert the public key to PEM format
$pem = $rsa_key->toString('PKCS1');

echo '<pre>';
echo $pem;
echo '</pre>';

// Create the data to be encrypted
$data = $session['id'] . '**' . $password;

// Encrypt the data
openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encoded, $rsa_key);
$encoded = bin2hex($encoded);

echo '<pre>';
echo $encoded;
echo '</pre>';
```